Storage of a large amount of data from a JSON file
I have a JSON file with links to around 320k pdf files. I need to acquire all of these files. Through my work we have a large amount of storage in NextCloud as well as access to Google Colab pro+.
I have mounted Google Colab to NextCloud using this tutorial: https://rizkyrajitha.hashnode.dev/connect-nextcloud-with-google-colab
I run the code through Google Colab to spare my shitty Mac. I loop through the JSON file, download the files and store them in a NextCloud folder, with no problem. It goes quickly for the first 15k, or so, files but then it slows down and eventyally almost stops completely. It is a large amount of data, so running it locally
Can anyone think of a better solution to retrive and store this large amount of data in a fairly convinent way, or optimize my current idea?

What is the type of NextCloud storage that you pick?

Hi Guillaume,
I am not quite sure tbh, I guess just the standard kind. It is a University account. Thank you

Do you feel the issue is related to the size/shape of your json config file or with the actual fetching of the pdf files?

IMO, if you have slowness after 15k PDF, I think you have hot spot in your storage system, therefore I asked to know your underlying infrastructure and solve this bottleneck

I feel like it is the size of the json file as fetching the the PDF files seems to work perfectly in the first part of the extraction.

It sounds very likely that a hot spot in your storage system is the problem
